# Simple Jenkins application to show gcc version

Tags: jenkins, bitbucket, jenkins-groovy

I am after a simple Jenkin application to show `gcc` version after each push to `bitbucket`.

Here is the `Jenkinsfile`:

```
pipeline {
    agent { docker { image 'kernelci/build-gcc-7_arm:3.3.3' } }
    stages {
        stage('build') {
            steps {
                sh 'gcc --version'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Bitbucket

```
Repository Settings/Post Webhooks:
     http://jenkins.SOMEADDRESS:8080/bitbucket-scmsource-hook/notify
```

After each push, the build does not start automatically but not a problem. I starts the builds manually.
However, The `Jenkin` build output result looks like this

```
Started by user MY_USERNAME
[Office365connector] No webhooks to notify
Building on master in workspace c:\w\PROJECTNAME
 > git.exe rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
 Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
 > git.exe config remote.origin.url http://bb.MYWEBSITE.COM/scm/bbb/MYREPO.git # timeout=10
 Fetching upstream changes from http://bb.MYWEBSITE.COM/scm/bbb/MYREPO.git
 > git.exe --version # timeout=10
 using GIT_ASKPASS to set credentials Credentials for Jenkins in Bitbucket
 > git.exe fetch --tags --progress http://bb.MYWEBSITE.COM/scm/bbb/MYREPO.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
Seen branch in repository origin/feature/LAST_BRANCH
Seen branch in repository origin/feature/BRANCH_A
Seen branch in repository origin/feature/BRANCH_B
Seen branch in repository origin/feature/BRANCH_C
Seen branch in repository origin/feature/BRANCH_D
Seen branch in repository origin/feature/BRANCH_E
Seen branch in repository origin/feature/BRANCH_F
Seen branch in repository origin/feature/BRANCH_G
Seen 8 remote branches
 > git.exe show-ref --tags -d # timeout=10
 Checking out Revision e3152f566543dfb813c6e33ac0d1099da7ec26a6 (origin/LAST_BRANCH)
 > git.exe config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
 > git.exe checkout -f e3152f566543dfb813c6e33ac0d1099da7ec26a6
 Commit message: "Merge branch 'feature/BRANCH_A' into LAST_BRANCH"
First time build. Skipping changelog.
[Office365connector] No webhooks to notify
Finished: SUCCESS
```

It does not look like loading a dock in 4 seconds. I do not see any `gcc` version on the screen either. Where is the problem from?

Is it from `Jenkinsfile`?

Comment: where is your jenkins file ? remote repo ? locally? inline script ?did you really load Jenkinsfile in the pipeline job?

Comment: @yarin, Thank you for your comment. `Jenkinsfile` is located on the root folder of remote repo. The name of file is `Jenkinsfile`. I am not sure what you mean by `did you really load Jenkinsfile in the pipeline job? `. My Jenkins setting is ` Repository URL`  set `Git` and set `Repository URL`. Anything else that I should set?

Comment: your job is type of pipeline job ? did you set the path for the jenkins file in the job configuration ?